# HTML Audio Control Via Script

Tags: html, css, audio, web

I'm fairly new to HTML so bear with me...  I'm trying to start an audio clip through a script on my webpage but I'm having difficulties figuring out how to do this.  Here is subset of my HTML code I'm trying to work with:

```
<body id="body">
   <embed id="audio" src="song.wav" loop="true" hidden="true" autostart="true">
   <script>
      ...
      if(state==1)
      {
         document.getElementById("audio").autostart = "true"
      }
      else
      {
         document.getElementById("audio").autostart = "false"
      }
      ...
   </script>
</body>
```

My goal is to toggle this audio depending on that status of a variable within the script.  what I have above doesn't work but I feel like I'm almost there... Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up going with a different implementation however I'm not partiularly happy with the result.  This works in Chrome but not IE and I'm not sure about Safari:  var snd = new Audio("song.wav"); snd.play();  Any ideas about a more platform agnostic solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Don't enclose **true and false** in double quotes

```
 if(state==1)
      {
         document.getElementById("audio").autostart = true;
      }
      else
      {
         document.getElementById("audio").autostart = false;
      }
```

Comment: This makes sense as the script is interpreted differently than the html code.  Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work though...  I set autostart to "false" in the html code and to true in the script and my clip isn't playing.  Perhaps is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: @DanSnyder do you see any error in browsers console? Whenever you are working with js or jquery and something isn't working that's the first place you should look for. If there aren't any errors then try simple console.log or alert statements just to make sure if your function is being called.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  I didn't see any errors so I logged to console and I do seem to be resolving into my conditional statement.  So I'm reaching that code, it just isn't doing what I expect it to.  Maybe this has to do with using an embed tag vs audio?

Answer (score 0):

Apply either true or false without quotation or assign 0 either 1